# Media session example

Tags: visual-studio-2008, multimedia, ms-media-foundation

I'm new to **media foundation**. Could anyone help me with **video playback sample code using Media session** technique. I want to add a MFT for a third party decoder (to decode H264 video files). Please help me with code which is already working on Media Foundation.

Comment: There are plenty of samples you can download from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including video and audio playback.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside `Samples -> Multimedia -> Mediafoundation -> Decoder` in your Windows SDK installation directory. If you have not installed the SDK yet, get it [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3138). It contains an example MPEG2 decoder MFT. Also, please do not put so many clauses when you make a request. We can help you with the code but, can not assure that it works with Media Foundation fool-proof.